# VBA change specific bit of date

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a spreadsheet with pre written dates in order in a dd/mm/yyyy format, but i want to be able to change the entire sheet so that when i select a month from a drop down list it changes all the dates so they stay starting at the 1st through to the 31st, but only the month changes, using visual basic. I can use this to set specific dates,

```
Range("C3") = Format(DateSerial(Year:=2005, Month:=2, Day:=3), "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

But can i change just the month using something like this for example

```
Range("C3") = Format(DateSerial(Month:=5), "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: `so they stay starting at the 1st through to the 31st` what should happen if you change 31 december to febrary?

Comment: thats going to be a later bit of script where i will remove the sections outside of a months day range.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Function MakeDates(startDate As Date) As Date()

    Dim myDates() As Date, myYear As Integer, myMonth As Integer, daysInMonth As Integer
    Dim firstOfMonth As Date, firstOfNextMonth As Date, d As Integer
    myYear = Year(startDate)
    myMonth = Month(startDate)

    firstOfMonth = DateSerial(myYear, myMonth, 1)
    firstOfNextMonth = DateSerial(myYear, myMonth + 1, 1)
    daysInMonth = DateDiff("d", firstOfMonth, firstOfNextMonth)
    ReDim myDates(daysInMonth - 1)
    For d = 1 To daysInMonth
        myDates(d - 1) = DateSerial(myYear, myMonth, d)

    Next d
    MakeDates = myDates
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this

```
Dim d
d = MakeDates(#2/1/2014#)
Range("A1").Resize(rowsize:=31).Value = ""
Range("A1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(d) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(d)
```

That second to last line will remove the excess dates for you.

You should have your range formatted as a date. You can do that in code or just do it once in Excel. The latter is probably easier.